# Unable to get DOM elements in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

Using a simply structure:

```
<div id="a1" aura:id="a1">
    <div>Test Text</div>
</div>
```

In the helper I am attempting to do:

```
var a = component.find("a1").getElement();
```

Then get the *childNodes* but it keeps throwing an error. When debugging I am getting the following Proxy -> Target -> HTMLCollection with the only property being the length. The length property has the following message:

> length: [Exception: TypeError: Illegal invocation at HTMLCollection.remoteFunction (:2:14) at

No matter what I try to do with locker enabled I cannot access the HTML array. I know I am missing something basic here.

I am essentially trying to iterate through the nodelist, compare the classes, and set the disabled flag......

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this during the `aura:valueInit` command? If so, it won't work, because the DOM hasn't been rendered yet. Move your action to at least `afterRender`. For example, this code works:

---

```
<aura:application >
    <div id="a1" aura:id="a1">
        <div class="someClass">Test Text</div>
    </div>
    <ui:button label="Show" press="{!c.click}" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    click: function(component) {
        var div = component.find("a1").getElement();
        [].forEach.call(div.childNodes, v => console.log(v.className));
    }
})
```

---

Please note that an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) cannot be directly iterated over in a for loop, because it is a live list. Instead, you need to use Array.prototype.forEach, as demonstrated in the code above. Also, as demonstrated above, I performed the action after rendering (as a button click).

Comment: I was able to use regular for loop on the div.childNodes and it works .Note forEach did not work but normal for loop just works .Try the below var div = component.find("div1").getElement();

        for(var i=0 ; i<div.childNodes.length ;i++){
                console.log(div.childNodes[i].outerHTML);
                console.log(div.childNodes[i].className);
            }

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I was referring to the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop. Of course, you can use the index for loop, but this is usually not recommended.

Comment: index for loops are faster as per my research .What stops you from using the indexed for loop ?

Comment: Also looking at the Locker API viewer http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV.The child nodes of a secure document is an Object and not a Node List

Comment: @MohithShrivastava It's an Object generically, but it's still a proxy NodeList, not an Array. This means you can't write `div.childNodes.forEach(v => ...)`. Also, inlined functions with forEach seems to work just as fast as a simple for loop (try it out [here](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/66)). There are two reasons why forEach: (1) no hoisting of variables to function scope, and (2) less code to write/more legible. I don't know about you, but I'm a "lazy" programmer, and would rather write less code than more...  

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling getElements() method on the component returned from the find call?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm

Comment: I am using getElement() without the s. When I change to using getElements() I have the same issue when trying to get to the childNodes. Instead of a element I get the error in the "length" property as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`getElements()` Returns the array of elements in the DOM rendered by the component.see the example you have to access below mentioned

**Component:**

```
  <aura:application >
        <ui:button label="getEle" press="{!c.press}" />
        <div id="a1" aura:id="a1">
            <div>Test Text</div>
        </div>

    </aura:application>
```

Controller:

```
press : function(component, event, helper) {
         console.log(component.find("a1").getElements()[0].childNodes[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Nope. No matter how I do it the child nodes always return that error for the length and that is the only property available.

Comment: @eric I have tested it ,correctly rendering to me. can you edit the question with controller code what you have tried .

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like bug in the chrome rather locker service.To confirm its a bug in console.log method with the Proxy object ,just ran the same code in the firefox and was able to see the proxy object with child Nodes .

Run the below and you should check the console output ,

```
var a = component.find("a1").getElement();
console.log(a.childNodes.length);
for(var i=0 ; i<a.childNodes.length ;i++){
    console.log(a.childNodes[i].outerHTML);
}
```

You will see all the child elements .